# Yii2 не подключается widget

Tags: yii

Всем привет!

Немогу подлючить виджет в Yii2, вот сам виджет

```
<h1>Виджет</h1>
<?= testwidget::widget() ?>
```

и на это срочке выдается ошибка: Class 'testwidget' not found

В чем может быть проблема? Делал по уроку https://webformyself.com/yii2-vidzhety/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Проверьте в какой папке у Вас находится класс testwidget'a
- Путь к виджету должен совпадать с его Namespace
- testwidget должен расширять базовый класс Widget, при этом должен быть либо полный путь до класса с пространством имен, либо используйте use yii\widgets\widget;

Иными словами:

1. Кладем файл TestWidget.php в папку /widgets (в корне сервера, не
   надо засовывать его в /vendor/yiisoft/yii/widgets)
2. Указываем ему
   пространство имен папки этой папки - `Namespace widgets;`
3. Под
   пространством имен прописываем путь к базову Widget'у -

   `use yii\base\Widget;`
4. Прописываем сам класс - `class TestWidget extends Widget {}`

Comment: спасибо, попробую